# image transport using rosbridge

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

What is the best way to transport an image (e.g. .png or .jpg) via rosbridge? Is it possible? What I don't want is, to use an url for a stream, because I need to transport several different images stored on a harddisk.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35460/image-transport-using-rosbridge/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on 2012-06-01**:
What did you call "transport"?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the image_transport [tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials) to get an idea of how to move images.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) on 2012-06-03**:
As far as moving the images over rosbridge once you have them published as ROS transports, check out [mjpeg_server](http://ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server) or the wsview.js script in the scripts directory of rosbridge.